# Why does categorizing a Dask DataFrame constructed from a Parquet file drastically increase its size?

Tags: dask, parquet, fastparquet

Here is the archetypal scenario:

1. I construct a Dask DataFrame from a set of Parquet files written by FastParquet
2. I run `categorize()` on the DataFrame. Quite a few categories become newly "known."
3. I save the DataFrame to a new Parquet file-set via FastParquet

The new Parquet files now take up several times more disk space than the original set! Now, it's not that I care about disk space—I have enough—but rather I seek understanding:

Even if the original file-set's categories were not "known," they still had to have been in the file-set's disk space *somewhere*. If anything, I might expect a *decrease* in disk usage, if the original file-set's categorical columns were not using a dictionary to begin with.

So, yeah, just trying to understand. What gives?

Comment: Please provide some example code showing this happening

Comment: @mdurant it is not really feasible for me to do that. I have to stop the computation around 8 hours in, when it is about 9% completed and the partially-written Parquet file-set is already ~300GB (versus the original's size of 66GB).

If you requested example code because behavior should _not_ be occurring, that is good for me to know, standalone.

Comment: It *sounds* wrong. You could demonstrate with perhaps just one columns and a much smaller sample of the data - but really, we want to see the specific code calls you are making.

Comment: Hello @mdurant, I know it is not exactly what you are seeking, but I am telling you anyway in the hope to help a little. The following things make Dask become unresponsive, to the point where the progress bar freezes and Jupyter's "interrupt kernel" has no effect: (1) when `set_index()` follows `categorize()`; (2) when `to_parquet()` follows `categorize()`. Keep in mind it's ~1TB uncompressed of mostly (high-cardinality) categorical data. I am not bumping against the limit of available RAM. I don't need any further help though because I'm going a different route. Anyway, be well, Martin.

Comment: @murant, oh I forgot to add: this behavior (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304385/why-does-categorizing-a-dask-dataframe-constructed-from-a-parquet-file-drastical#comment97583156_55304385) occurs using both the local threaded and local multiprocessing schedulers. Also, to be clear I am not totally ditching Dask, rather I am "going a different route" in a less dramatic way which is  more constrained to this immediate task.

Comment: Sounds like a new question of bug report - please try to produce a minimum but full example.